# Efficient algorithm for finding how many times x appears in a sorted array

Tags: java, algorithm, search

I was given a sorted array of n integer values and an integer x. What would be the most efficient algorithm for finding how many times x appears in this array?

I thought about binary search and when I get to x then I split left and right to see if there is more x to add to my count, but I wanted to know if there is any other solution for this.

Comment: Binary search is the best option.

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-number-of-occurrences-in-a-sorted-array/

Comment: A binary search is the best way IMHO.

Comment: Hint: you can tweak the "standard" binary search to always find the first element greater than a given `x` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if the number of occurrences of `x` in the array can be considered a constant compared to the length of the array, your binary search approach would give you an `O(log(N)` algorithm, and you can't do better than that.

However, if, for example, all the elements of your array are `x`, or half the elements are `x`, the second part of your algorithm (`split left and right to see if there is more x to add to my count`) will take linear time.

You can avoid that if you use two more binary searched to find the indices of the first x and last x in the array. You can do it, for example, by running a binary search on x-1 and x+1 (assuming this is an int array).

This will give you O(log(N)) running time regardless of how many `x`s are in the array.

Answer (score 0):

it's integers and the list is sorted.

Use a splitting search algorithm where you split at index:

```
indexToSplit = (int) x*(an - a1)/n
```

Where:

```
x is your integer to find
an is the last integer in the list
a1 is the first integer in the list
n is the size of the list
```

Assuming your list is sorted from lowest to highest

This is a heuristic which *can* be better than binary sort, but depends on how uniformly the integers in the list are distributed